# How to scrape data from HTML tabs with Zapier?

Tags: zapier

I'm new to Zapier. I'm using it with a webhook to my Discord channel to get feeds from a website through RSS. Unfortunately the data I receive is raw HTML. What I need only is to get the src of the `<img>` tab, which is inside `<td>` tabs of a `<table>`. So I need to figure out a way how to scrape the content from `<td>` tabs.

Can someone provide me guidance on this matter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Python has a built in library for this (https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) that you can use in a Code by Zapier step https://zapier.com/help/code-python/).

Even though Zapier supports Javascript as well - I definitely recommend Python to do this!

Comment: I'm not fluent in Python but I'll try.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this useful wrapper API for Python’s Beautiful Soup BS4.

You can pass your HTML to the API, and call the popular BS4 methods and request for any params.

This should do the trick

https://rapidapi.com/dollarbill99/api/beautifulsoup-wrapper